# Get last week's data from a table with a creation date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using the following query for retrieving last week data,but I am getting error as

> Postgres ERROR: syntax error at or near "CAST"   Position: 127

I don't know where the error is:

```
SELECT count(*), extract(day from createdon) AS period
FROM orders
WHERE servicename =:serviceName AND  createdon BETWEEN 
    CAST(NOW() AS CAST(DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW()) AS INTEGER-7)) AND
    CAST(NOW() AS CAST(DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW()) AS INTEGER))
GROUP BY  extract(day from createdon)
ORDER BY extract(day from createdon);
```

Comment: Your - 7 should be after the parenthesis, because now it's looking for a INTEGER-7 data type.

Comment: i tried it but still same error....Baby

Comment: Marc i  changed ...but it shows the same error with"\n" at position 127

Comment: `CAST(expr1 AS CAST(expr2 AS <type>))` is certainly invalid. I can't even guess, what you tried to achieve with that.

Comment: Also: are you sure you want the ANSI SQL's `DOW` concept, instead of the `ISODOW`? (`DOW` weeks starts on sunday, while `ISODOW` weeks on monday: just like with `date_trunc('week', ...)` in [a_horse_with_no_name's anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41714777/1499698))

Comment: i need DOW as it starts from sunday

Answer (score 5):

You are overcomplicating things. To get last week's data, just get everything after the "start of this week" minus 7 days:

The "start of the this week" can be evaluated using `date_trunc('week', current_date)`.

If you subtract 7 days you get the *start* of the previous week: `date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '7' day`. If you subtract 1 day, you get the *end* of the previous week.

`date_trunc` always uses Monday as the start of the week, so if your week starts on Sunday, just subract one more, e.g. `date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 8` will be the Sunday of the previous week

Putting that all together you get:

```
SELECT count(*), extract(day from createdon) AS period
FROM orders
WHERE servicename =:serviceName 
  AND createdon 
      between date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 7 
          and date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 1
GROUP BY extract(day from createdon)
ORDER BY extract(day from createdon);
```

If your columns are timestamp columns you can simply cast `createdon` to a date to get rid of the time part:

```
  AND createdon::date 
      between date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 7 
          and date_trunc('week', current_date)::date
```

Note that a regular index on `createdon` will not be used for that condition, you would need to create an index on `createdon::date` if you need the performance.

If you can't (or don't want to) create such an index, you need to use something different then `between`

```
  AND createdon >= date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 7 
  AND createdon < date_trunc('week', current_date)::date
```

(Note the use of `<` instead of `<=` which is what `between is using)

Another option is to convert the date information to a combination of week and year:

```
AND to_char(createdon, 'iyyy-iw') = to_char(date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 7, 'iyyy-iw')
```

Note, that I used the [ISO week definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) for the above. If you are using a different week numbering system, you need a different [format mask](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) for the `to_char()` function.

Comment: Nah, `date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1' day` is midnight of 1 day before the end of the previous week / start of this week.

Comment: @pozs: I assumed those were `DATE` columns. If those are `timestamp` you are obviously right

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name right, that could work, but feels weird to widen the `date` column to do the comparison; `between date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 7 and date_trunc('week', current_date)::date - 1` could use indexes too (if it's a `date` column OFC).

Comment: @posz: you are right. If that is a date column, that is better

Comment: @pozs wat happens if i use the above query for timestamp....will it not give me exact result.....

Comment: @nandhini: see my edit, there are several other methods

Answer (score 0):

If you work with the North American week system (whose weeks start on Sunday), your original approach was good enough, just use the correct syntax of `CAST(<epr> AS <type>)`:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*),
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM createdon) period
FROM     orders
WHERE    servicename = 'Cell Tower Monitoring'
AND      createdon BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - CAST(EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE) AS INTEGER) - 7 
                       AND CURRENT_DATE - CAST(EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE) AS INTEGER) - 1
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM createdon)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM createdon);
```

**Note**: this assumes that `createdon` is a `DATE` column. If it's a `TIMESTAMP` (or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`), you need a slightly different version:

```
SELECT   COUNT(*),
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM createdon) period
FROM     orders
WHERE    servicename = 'Cell Tower Monitoring'
AND      createdon >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day' * (EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 7)
AND      createdon <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day' *  EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM createdon)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM createdon);
```

If you want to use the ISO week system (whose weeks start on Monday), then just use `ISODOW` instead of `DOW`. Or, you could use the `date_trunc('week', ...)` function, like in [@a_horse_with_no_name's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41714777/1499698).

If you want to use another week systems (f.ex. which starts on Saturday), you'll need some extra logic inside `CASE` expressions, as subtracting `1` from `DOW` will not give the expected results at the start of that kind of week (f.ex. on Saturday it would give the week 2 weeks before).